# How do I make a Navigational Drawer Activity open when the app launches in Android Studio?

Tags: android, launch, drawer

I am new to Android development (and development in general) and I'm working on a simple app. The app uses the built-in Navigational Drawer Activity template that comes with Android Studio. Everything is working correctly, but now my goal is to make it so that when the app launches, it starts with the Navigational Drawer expanded (opened). Currently, when you launch the app, it starts with the Navigational Drawer closed, and you have to click the little 3-line icon (hamburger) to open it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are use this line for open drawer in on create view after set up drawer

```
public void open()
{
mYourDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

hi please more detail read this line
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand... does this go in the MainActivity.java file?